# Is it wrong to not use Models on ASP NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

I've been working with ASP NET Web Forms for a while and we have been communicating with the database like this

```
 using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conexao))
            {
                try
                {
                    string sql = string.Format("SELECT ID_Cliente, Nome, Cnpj, FL_Filial FROM cadastro_cliente WHERE ID_Cliente = {0}", ID_Cliente);

                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
                    MySqlDataReader reader = null;

                    con.Open();
                    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        flf = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FL_Filial"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    string vLog = "#Erro#: " + ex.Message;
                    EscreveLog(vLog);
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

My question is, is it right if I use the same way to communicate with the database? Like not using Models or anything. Reminding that I'm new to ASP NET Razor Pages.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. (also: your con is automaticalls disposed once execution leaves the using-block - that's the whole point of using ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could program anything, Visual Studio allows you to do anything in Controllers. But.. see comments of Franz ! they are relevant. To avoid the pitfalls Franz has pointed out, I would recommend using Entity Framework instead of directly using SQL. That would introduce models (DBContext) anyway.

ASP.NET was designed for MVVM and the only difference with ASP.NET Core is the implementation. I would say the answer to this question is yes, skipping the model is wrong.. unless you do not want to adhere to **M**VVM programming methods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel